# Column Level Encryption backup

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I want to do column level encryption. For example:

```
--Create Master Key
USE EncryptTest
 GO
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION
BY PASSWORD = 'Test'
GO

--Create Server Cert
USE EncryptTest
 GO
CREATE CERTIFICATE EncryptTestCert
WITH SUBJECT = 'Test'
GO

/* Create Symmetric Key */
USE EncryptTest
 GO
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY TestTableKey
WITH ALGORITHM = TRIPLE_DES ENCRYPTION
BY CERTIFICATE EncryptTestCert
 GO
/* Encrypt the Column.*/
 USE EncryptTest
 GO
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY TestTableKey DECRYPTION
BY CERTIFICATE EncryptTestCert
UPDATE TestTable
SET EncryptSecondCol = ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('TestTableKey'),SecondCol)
GO

--View encrypted
USE EncryptTest
 GO
SELECT *
FROM TestTable
 GO
```

My question however, is how to back up the Cert or key?  The scenario being the DBA (not me of course) accidentally deletes the cert/key leaving the database secure, but useless.  I bring this up as I have seen more actual issues with someone flubbing security with a fat finger, then with actual security breaches.

Comment: The downvote is correct - I should have done more research on this before posting: As soon as I did, I found the below link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow the article at Microsoft TechNet on backing up a cert?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178578.aspx